# Add jQuery in dashboard when is already added in main plugin page

Tags: plugins, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi guys I have added jQuery and my jQuery fail to my main plugin page and it works great by this was.

```
    function load_scipt() {
        wp_register_script( 'reserveit', plugins_url( '/js/reserveit.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '2.5.1' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'reserveit' );

        wp_register_script( 'datetimepicker', plugins_url( '/lib/datetimepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-slider', 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'datetimepicker' );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-slider' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scipt' );


Now I need to add jQuery datepicker to input in my admin menu, but it isn't working here is the code.

function load_scipts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-widget' );


    wp_register_script( 'admin-menu', plugins_url( 'admin-menu.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ), '2.5.1' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'admin-menu' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' );
}

  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scipts' );
```

I tried everything but it isn't working. my path to files working but I have no idea where can the problem is.

this is my reserveit.js

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

```
    jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });

});
```

and this is my admin-menu.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {

    jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
});
```

Please if you have idea write comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to enqueue scripts for *admin* requests, you need to use the hook [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts). `wp_enqueue_scripts` is only for front end requests.